# Background color of CDialog and all the controls in that dialog is white instead of gray

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, colors, background

I'm migrating code from VS 2005 to VS 2010. I am facing a strange problem.. Few dialogs (which are derived from CDialog) when invoked is seen with white background and all of the controls have the white background too. I've tried a lot to find the cause but unable to. Please can someone suggest a way to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am migrating my application from VS 2003 to VS 2010. IN VS 2003 there is a user defined class called CDilaogEx and in VS 2010 there is a new MFC called **CDialogEx**. 
There is a confusion because of same name. 
After changing the user-defined class name and all its references to the new name I am able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is OS you are running? Is this effect the same on Windows 7 and XP?
Would it be possible for you to either attach project in question for us to debug?

Comment: @JohnCz.. I am running in WinXP. I have restrictions to post code in public forums. Now, I am finding strange problems.. only when SPY++ is running the dialog pops up with white background.. else the dialog hangs.. Can somebody help please?